# Adding a button that's unique in every post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, button, post

I want to make a button that's in a "if" loop that will unroll / show more images from the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. The problem is that it doesn't work when there are more post on page than one, because the same button is in all of the posts and all the images have the same class. Is there a way to make a unique button that will work only in it's post?

> ```
> <?php if (have_posts()) :   while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
>
> <?php the_content();    if (get_field('project_detail')) {
>  the_field('project_detail');
>  } ?>
>
> <img src="<?php echo the_field('visible_image_1'); ?>" /> 
>
> <button type="button">Show more</button> 
>
> <script> 
> $("button").click(function(){ $(".more").slideToggle(500); });
> </script> 
>
> <div class="more"> 
>  <img src="<?php echo the_field('hidden_image_1'); ?>" /> 
>  <img src="<?php echo the_field('hidden_image_2'); ?>" /> 
> </div>  
>
> <?php endwhile;
>  else :
>   echo '<p>No content found</p>';   endif;
>
> get_footer();   ?>
> ```

CSS

> .more {
>       display: none;
>   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :   while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content();    if (get_field('project_detail')) {
 the_field('project_detail');
 } ?>

<img src="<?php echo the_field('visible_image_1'); ?>" /> 

<button type="button" id="button<?php echo get_the_ID()?>">Show more</button> 

<script> 
$("#button<?php echo get_the_ID()?>").click(function(){ $(".more<?php echo get_the_ID()?>").slideToggle(500); });
</script> 

<div class="more<?php echo get_the_ID()?>"> 
 <img src="<?php echo the_field('hidden_image_1'); ?>" /> 
 <img src="<?php echo the_field('hidden_image_2'); ?>" /> 
</div>  

<?php endwhile;
 else :
  echo '<p>No content found</p>';   endif;

get_footer();   ?>
```

We are using a variable which will be added to each button ID, so they will be button1, button2, etc. Let me know if this works :)

Comment: The idea works :) but all the post show their hidden content when the button is pressed. I believe I could get the same effect by using something like: id="button<?php echo get_the_ID()?>" . But is there a way so I can make the class .more also be unique to its post? Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Yes, that would be an even prettier solution since we won't need the $i variable at all. I will edit my answer using that :)

Comment: Ok, I got it. There also has to be a change in the line : ...  $("#button<?php echo get_the_ID()?>").click(function(){ $("#more<?php echo get_the_ID()?>").slideToggle(500); });
</script>
<div class="opisy" id="more<?php echo get_the_ID()?>"> ...  So the script knows which images to show. Thank again! :)

Comment: You are right, I have added it in. Glad I could help! :)